# for..in loop Property does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: typescript

This code is not compiling (TypeScript v 2.9):

```
   class Foo {
      constructor(public key: string, public value: string) {
      }
    }

    const arr = new Array<Foo>();

    for (let foo in arr) {
          console.log(foo.key, foo.value)
    }
```

Here is same code on TypeScipt playground:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(public%20key%3A%20string%2C%20public%20value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20arr%20%3D%20new%20Array%3CFoo%3E()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20(let%20foo%20in%20arr)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(foo.key%2C%20foo.value)%0D%0A%7D

And the reason is:

[image]

Why TypeScript thinks that variable is the type of string and how to fix it but using `for..in` loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`for-in` will iterate the keys of an object, to iterate arrays use `for-of`

```
class Foo {
  constructor(public key: string, public value: string) {
  }
}

const arr = new Array<Foo>();

for (let foo of arr) {
      console.log(foo.key, foo.value)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `for (let foo of arr) {` instead of `for (let foo in arr) {`